# Why does HAProxy use HTTP OPTIONS for healtchecks, by default?

Tags: haproxy, http-options-method

According to the [HAProxy Configuration Reference](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-option%20httpchk), HAProxy uses an HTTP `OPTIONS` request for HTTP health checks, by default, with `option httpchk`.

Since I think it's implementation dependent whether web servers provide an HTTP `OPTIONS` handler or not, I wonder why HAProxy uses this request type by default. Is there any reasonable technical background?

Comment: Probably because it usually is used as an http reverse proxy/lb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They write the reasoning in the documentation you [link](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#4-option%20httpchk):

> <method>  ... When not set,
>             the "OPTIONS" method is used, as it generally requires low server
>             processing and is easy to filter out from the logs. ...